# How to see when I won a badge

Tags: support, reputation, badges

I am working on a project where I would like to show graphically when an user won a preselected badge, sorted by date...

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to get the information?  Via the API?  Or just the HTML page?  Or from [data.se]?

Comment: via API would be better, I dont want to crawl any web content

Answer (score 11):

If you visit your profile and then click on the badges tab, each badge will provide a link of the form `//stackoverflow.com/help/badges/{badgeId}/{badgeName_optional}?userid={userId}`.  Following one of these links gives you a list of when those badges were awarded.  For example, a list of [when I was awarded a Reviewer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer?userid=4320665).  I don't know if there is an API for this, but the information is there in the DOM.

[Tunaki did some digging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336635/how-to-see-when-i-won-a-badge#comment406154_336640) and found an API that lets you retrieve a list of badges associated with a user.  According to the [API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-on-users), it can even let you sort or filter by badge characteristics, but it's certainly capable of fetching all the badges a specific user has earned.  The handy demo UI suggests using this link to see all your badges in a (slightly cluttered) object:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/982161/badges?order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow

Comment: There is a way to do that via the API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-on-users

Comment: But that API response doesn't include the dates when the badges were awarded.